# word scramble with pointers in an array. Crashes when run

Tags: c

I am new to arrays with pointers, and I am trying to make an array of pointers word scramble game that allows 3 tries to guess the word before the game ends. Basically, I have created a function that scrambles a string. Then, that string is sent to a new string, which is shown to the user. The user then enters their guess. I am getting no signal from my compiler on what is wrong.. It just crashes when it is run. I believe the error is when I am sending the pointer to the method. Could someone please tell me why this error is happening? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void scramble(char *strings)
{
    int length = strlen(strings), i, randomNum;
    char temp;

    for(i = 0; i < length/2; i++)
    {
        randomNum = rand()%length;
        temp = strings[i];
        strings[i] = strings[length - randomNum];
        strings[length - randomNum] = temp;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i, tries, NUMWORDS;
    char *words[] = { "pumpkin", "cantalope", "watermelon", "apple", "kumquat" };
    char *scramWords, *user;
    NUMWORDS = strlen(words);
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i = 0; i < NUMWORDS; i++)
    {
        scramWords[i] = words[i];
        scramble(scramWords[i]);
    }

    printf("How to play: You get 3 tries to guess each scrambled word.\n");
    for(i = 0; i < NUMWORDS; i++)
    {
        tries = 0;
        while(tries !=4)
        {
            if(tries == 3)
            {
                printf("You Lose\n");
                return 0;
            }
            printf("Unscramble: %s\n", scramWords[i]);
            gets(user);
            if(strcmp(user, words[i]) == 0)
            {
                printf("Correct!\n");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                tries++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("You Win!");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `NUMWORDS = strlen(words);` -  um, `strlen` is for finding the length of nulchar-terminated strings, not the size of some fixed array of `char*`. There are a plethora of *significant* warnings in your code as well. Turn up your compiler warnings to pedantic levels, turn on warnings-as-errors, and fix everything that is flagged (there are at least five such problems I see at first glance).

Comment: If randomnum is 0, you're trying to access array[length]. That's one error to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You must not try to modify string literals, or you will invoke *undefined behavior*. Copy strings before editing them instead of just assigning pointers.
- `length - randomNum` may be `length` when `randomNum` is 0.
- `strlen(words)` won't be the number of elements in `words`. You can use `sizeof(words) / sizeof(*words)`.
- You must allocate some buffer to `scramWords` and `user` before writing anything there.
- You shouldn't use `gets()`, which has unavoidable risk of buffer overrun, deprecated in C99 and removed from C11.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void scramble(char *strings)
{
    int length = strlen(strings), i, randomNum;
    char temp;

    for(i = 0; i < length/2; i++)
    {
        randomNum = rand()%length;
        temp = strings[i];
        strings[i] = strings[length - randomNum - 1];
        strings[length - randomNum - 1] = temp;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int i, tries, NUMWORDS;
    char *words[] = { "pumpkin", "cantalope", "watermelon", "apple", "kumquat" };
    char **scramWords, user[1024], *lf;
    NUMWORDS = sizeof(words) / sizeof(*words);
    srand(time(NULL));
    scramWords = malloc(sizeof(*scramWords) * NUMWORDS);
    if(scramWords == NULL)
    {
        perror("malloc");
        return 1;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < NUMWORDS; i++)
    {
        scramWords[i] = malloc(strlen(words[i]) + 1); /* +1 for terminating null-character */
        if(scramWords[i] == NULL)
        {
            perror("malloc");
            return 1;
        }
        strcpy(scramWords[i], words[i]);
        scramble(scramWords[i]);
    }

    printf("How to play: You get 3 tries to guess each scrambled word.\n");
    for(i = 0; i < NUMWORDS; i++)
    {
        tries = 0;
        while(tries !=4)
        {
            if(tries == 3)
            {
                printf("You Lose\n");
                return 0;
            }
            printf("Unscramble: %s\n", scramWords[i]);
            if(fgets(user, sizeof(user), stdin) == NULL)
            {
                puts("fgets failed");
                return 1;
            }
            if((lf = strchr(user, '\n')) != NULL)
            {
                *lf = '\0'; /* remove newline character after string read */
            }
            if(strcmp(user, words[i]) == 0)
            {
                printf("Correct!\n");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                tries++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("You Win!");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to get away without using 'mallocs()'? I am using ASCII C and I don't believe it is compatible. I am getting an "incompatible conversion from void to char".

Comment: @Submersed24 Based on the message, I don't think you are using C but you should be using C++. [`new[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new[]/) can be used to allocate arrays in C++.

Answer (score 1):

you have a few issues in your code:

*1),* `scramble`gets a `char *` but here 
`scramWords[i] = words[i];
scramble(scramWords[i]);`
 you provide it with a `char` so define your `scramWords` as a `char**` instead of `char*`

*2)* You don't allocate space when declaring a pointer - that could lead to segfault. Use `malloc` or before accessing the pointer.

*3)* When assigning strings from one pointer to another use strcpy, not `= operator`

*4)* Use  `sizeof(words)/sizeof(*words)` instead of `NUMWORDS = strlen(words);`

That should leave you with a working piece of code, but, as said in comments - take care of your warnings!

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense, since it is a pointer to a pointer, you need 2 pointers? Also, could you please explain how to allocate space without using mallocs()? I understand what it does, but I don't think I can use that in ASCII C

Comment: why not use malloc? and did you mean ANSI C? malloc should work there...